# How `impl From<AsRef<A>> for B` correctly: "the size for values of type `(dyn AsRef<address2::A> + 'static)` cannot be known at compilation time"

Tags: rust

My code:

```
struct A {}

struct B {}

impl From<AsRef<A>> for B {
    fn from(_: AsRef<A>) -> Self {
        todo!()
    }
}
```

The error it produces:

```
error[E0277]: the size for values of type `(dyn AsRef<address2::A> + 'static)` cannot be known at compilation time
   --> src/address2.rs:15:6
    |
15  | impl From<AsRef<A>> for B {
    |      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ doesn't have a size known at compile-time
    |
    = help: the trait `Sized` is not implemented for `(dyn AsRef<address2::A> + 'static)`
```

Answer (score 2):

[AsRef](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.AsRef.html) is a trait, witch does not have a fixed size. The size would depend on the struct that is implementing it.

You can use generics to solve this error witch says to the compiler "for each type that implements `AsRef<A>`, implement `From<T>`".

```
impl<T> From<T> for B
where T: AsRef<A> {
    fn from(_: T) -> Self {
        todo!()
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a side question, is it idiomatic to implement this? Why not rather `impl From<&A>` and leave the as_ref() call for the caller?